# When will UITableView reloadData have updated the visibleCells?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, timing

I have a UITableView instance `tableView` that displays data from a server.

The `tableView` will have to wait until the data is received, and then gets a call to it's `reloadData` method. All fine, works great.

Now I have a particular method that I want to perform right after the tableView finishes creating the first set of `visibleCells`. For this example I'll call the method `performFancyActionOnVisibleCells`. It seems however, that the reloadData action is asynchronous, so I can't just do

```
[tableView reloadData];
[self performFancyActionOnVisibleCells];
```

Because the visibleCells are still empty when that second line is executed, I will have to wait a bit before calling it. Which brings me to my question.

To my knowledge there is no delegate method like `tableView:didFinishReloadingData`. But if I'd want to call `performFancyActionOnVisibleCells` with the certainty that `reloadData` has finished updating the `visibleCells` property, where would that be?

Cheers,
EP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly, I am not aware of any delegate callback for what you're looking for.

But, `reloadData` will call `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath]` on each of your visable rows so you could put a call at the bottom of that method.

I don't think that `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath]` gets called for every cell in your table but will get called by UIKit as required before the cell is made visable (for example, when scrolling).

Comment: Yes tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called for every row, but I'm looking for the first next opportunity after the table is done filling rows. Keeping a counter in this method won't cut it, for reasons of iPhone portrait, landscape, iPad, etc. I guess I'll just keep looking.

Comment: I'll humor your question with the answer-mark, though the info is not new, it's what I resorted to after all other options failed. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Damien sounds right but I think that you should look at your strategy...Users may not be expecting something to popup (at a random time). I think you should display the cells first and then populate them. Use a progress indicator until the data has arrived. Then when the data arrives, draw it into the cell and thereafter you can run your fancyActionMethod. I hope this helps!